# PHP internal server error when using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

When I was working on localhost,all my 9 pages were making ajax requests without any error. but when I uploaded the website to a server, ajax in all pages worked without any error in all pages but the login page! When I try to login it gives me the error

```
GET http://www.example.com/ajax/login.php?email=admin@me.com&password=1291995 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

here is the login code that I use in my website

```
function login(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            if(xmlhttp.responseText=="")
                {document.getElementById("errorInLogin").style.display="block";
                console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);}
            else{
                window.open("profile.php?id="+xmlhttp.responseText,"_self");
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax/login.php?email=" + document.getElementById("email").value + "&password=" + document.getElementById("password").value, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and this is my login php file code

```
require_once ('../functions/DataBaseConnection.php');  
if (mysqli_real_escape_string($con,empty($_GET['email']))||empty(mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['password'])))
    {echo "";die("");}
else
{
    $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['email']);
    $p=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['password']); 

    $sql = "SELECT `userid`, `email`,`password` FROM `user` WHERE email='$email'";
    $userQuery=$con->query($sql) or die(mysqli_($con));
    if($user=mysqli_fetch_array($userQuery))
    {
        $uid=$user['userid'];
        $pass=$user['password'];
        if(md5($p)==$pass) 
        {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $uid;
            echo $uid;
            die("");
        }   
        else 
        {
           echo "";die("");}
    }
    else 
        {echo "";die("");}
}
```

Is there any thing with my code that would cause this error?
The weird thing that Ajax works in all my files but this file, What could be wrong? and how can I fix it?

Comment: Check the error logs, the answer should be there.

Comment: The same error displayed in the browser is in the error logs file. there is no description about the error so I can google it.

Comment: Does the PHP page work by itself?

Comment: What do you mean by "by itself"?

Comment: Go to the PHP page, bypassing the AJAX. Does the PHP page work?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It gives me the same error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: You have now ruled out the AJAX. You'll have to track down the error in your PHP and fix it.